# How do I resolve an "Invalid Node" error in the ACL tutorial in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I created an application using the method described in the [CakePHP Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Tutorials-Examples/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application.html) but after I try to log in there is an error which says,

```
DbAcl::allow() - Invalid node [CORE\cake\libs\controller\components\acl.php, line 325]
```

I did exactly same as mentioned in the website but after loggin in I
am given this error message. Please help me rectify this.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to provide an answer, but that error means that something is wrong in your ACL trees, ARO or ACO, *or* you're sending the wrong parameter to allow().

Try using the acl console to find out whether your ARO/ACO trees are organized properly, as described in the tutorial. If they are not, truncate your ACL tables and start inserting from scratch. But very carefully this time! :-P

Answer (score 0):

yes. something is definitely wrong because as described in the method there the aros tables should have the structure exactly to that of mentioned in that section. when I created groups using the CRUD generated by cakephp all went properly to the database but the users info is not updated in the aros table. I will again give it a try to see if I am doing something wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Super old question, but, I came across this problem and couldn't find an answer to my problem (even in this thread).

My problem actually was that I had a method with the same name that the controller, let me explain what I mean with some code:

```
class Users extends AppController{
  public function users(){
  }
}
```

Changing the method name fixed the problem for me.

PS: using cakePHP 1.2